# Airborne::InvalidJsonError: Api request returned invalid json

Tags: json, ruby, api, airborne

I'm getting below error while testing sample api in Airborne Ruby.

> Airborne::InvalidJsonError: Api request returned invalid json
>    /Users/balamurugan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.13/lib/airborne/base.rb:73:in
>   rescue in json_body
>   /Users/balamurugan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.13/lib/airborne/base.rb:73:in
>   json_body
>   /Users/balamurugan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.13/lib/airborne/request_expectations.rb:139:in call_with_path
>   /Users/balamurugan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/airborne-0.2.13/lib/airborne/request_expectations.rb:18:in expect_json ./postapinew_spec.rb:16:in block (2 levels) in '
>
> -e:1:in `load'
>
> -e:1:in `'
>
> ---
>
> --- Caused by: ---
>
> JSON::ParserError:   765: unexpected token at ''   /Users/balamurugan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/common.rb:156:in
>   `parse'

## Code:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'airborne'
require 'json'

describe 'postapivalidation' do

  it 'should validate post api' do
    post 'http://localhost:9997/test',
         { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' , 'Accept' => 'application/json' },
         { 'params' => {'param1' => 'value1' , 'param2' => 'value2' } }
    expect_status 200
    expect_json(name: 'Alex')
  end
end
```

Issue is '`except_json`' related methods are not working for post *API*. But I got valid '`except_json`' results for get api.

How to solve this issue???

Comment: The exception says that the return json format is wrong, please check it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aristotll. The same api I checked in Postman and got valid json response. The problem is in only airborne 'except_json' methods..